# Irobot create Python script

Tags: ros, python, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hola!
I am writing a python script, to run teleop_twist_keyboard.py for irobot create, by opening just one terminal in which I will call the python script.
This script should open roscore, then it will open a new terminal and run rosrun irobot_create_2_1 driver.py and finally open another terminal and it will run rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py.
So I want to write just one command in one konsole and then it will automatically open the new terminals and call for the 3 functions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43417/irobot-create-python-script/) by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-09-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-09-08**:
What is your question?

**Comment by [andreapatri](https://answers.ros.org/users/1713/andreapatri/) on 2012-09-08**:
How can I open a konsole terminal from a python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question, but this sounds like exactly the kind of thing that launch files are used for.  Using a launch file you could easily launch all of the nodes that you are interested in, automatically start a new `roscore` if one is needed, and control the inputs and outputs for each individual node (if for example you wanted each node to launch in a different terminal window).  All of this could be accomplished with a single call to `roslaunch`.  Here is a minimalist example that may do approximately what you want:

```
<launch>
  <!-- start first node and roscore if needed: -->
  <node pkg="teleop_twist_keyboard" name="keyboard_control" 
    type="teleop_twist_keyboard.py" output="screen"
    respawn="true" launch-prefix="xterm -rv -e" />
  <!-- start second node: -->
  <node pkg="irobot_create_2_1" name="irobot_driver"
    type="driver.py" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

Note that I have used the `launch-prefix` tag in the first node entry to force the node to open in a new `xterm` window.  More about launch files can be found [here](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch) and available XML tags [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML)

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2012-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1